# Nginx php-fpm 404 error for one request and not another

Tags: php, nginx, configuration, http-status-code-404, fpm

I am hosting multiple php slim applications on the same server. They are located at the path `apis/'tier'/'organization'/'appName'/'version'` so for example `apis/FreeTierSmall/master/exampleApp/v1`.

I am using Nginx with php-fpm and am getting a very weird bug. I am trying to redirect any requests that start with `apis/master/` to `apis/FreeTierSmall/master`. I've turned on the Nginx rewrite_log and can see that the files get redirected correctly. I get the correct result if I try `apis/FreeTierSmall/master/example/v1`. However, I get a 404 error if I try `apis/master/example/v1` which redirects to the same php file. I know the redirect is working because I can see it in the logs. It seems that there is some problem with php-fpm. I am adding a header to the php-fpm execution so I know that it is calling the correct script. For some reason though a request of the same file is producing a 404 error in one case and not the other.

Is there some parameter that could cause the same file passed to fpm to work in one instance and not the other?

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
user nginx www-data;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main_timed  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                            '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe $upstream_cache_status'
                            'FPM - $document_root - $fastcgi_script_name > $request';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main_timed;
    # error_log /dev/stderr notice;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    # error_log above can be debug
    rewrite_log on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        sendfile off;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html;
        error_page 404 /404.html;

        # NOTE: Once you use last, that is the last redirect you can do. You must find the file after that.

        # HEALTH CHECK
        location /apis/FreeTierSmall/elb-status {
          access_log off;
          return 200 'A-OK!';
          # because default content-type is application/octet-stream,
          # browser will offer to "save the file"...
          # the next line allows you to see it in the browser so you can test
          add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        }

        # NORMAL API PATHS
        location /apis/ {

            #rewrite the old apis
            rewrite ^/apis/master/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)(.*)$ /apis/FreeTierSmall/master/$1/$2/api.php$3 last;
            rewrite ^/apis/interfaceop/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)(.*)$ /apis/FreeTierSmall/interfaceop/$1/$2/api.php$3 last;
            # add api.php to the path of the file
            rewrite ^/apis/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)(.*)$ /apis/$1/$2/$3/$4/api.php$5 last;
        }

        # ANY OTHER FILES
        location / {
            # try to serve the file, the directory, or a 404 error
            add_header X-debug-message-2 "A static file was served or 404 error $uri" always;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /robots.txt; # Need to change back to =404
        }

        # ERRORS
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /var/lib/nginx/html;
        }

        # PHP FILES
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php {
            add_header X-debug-message-5 "fastCGI -> .php $document_root$fastcgi_script_name" always;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        # SECURITY CONCERNS
        # deny access to . files, for security
        location ~ /\. {
            log_not_found off;
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the issue is that the URI of the request doesn't get changed with rewrite. Slim was providing the 404 error because the route didn't exist, and the route didn't exist because the URI never got changed by rewrite. So, rewrite doesn't actually change the request parameters it's just used to decide what file is going to be served. This is ok for most use cases but horrible for apis... a very odd error to debug. Good luck whoever runs into this in the future.

The solution: use proxy_pass.

```
location /apis/master/ {
    # Reroutes /apis/master/* to /apis/FreeTierSmall/master/* correctly!
    proxy_pass http://localhost:80/apis/FreeTierSmall/master/;
}
```